# How do i power mock a final class of Feign client Response object while testing catch block

Tags: junit, junit-jupiter

> ***<sup>I have this method for which iam trying to write mockito junit using jupiter .</sup>***

```
    public static String getErrorContent(final Response response) {

        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(response.body().asInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            log.warn("Unable to read response body", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
   i tried writing junits as follows

   public class ErrorStringUtilityTest {  
          @Mock
          Response response;

      @Test 
      public void testErrorStringUtility() { 
      final Map<String,
      Collection<String>> headers; 
          final String expectedValue = "error message";
      Exception exception=assertThrows(IOException.class,()->{
      ErrorStringUtility.getErrorContent(response); });  
      String actualMessage=exception.getMessage();
          assertEquals(actualMessage,expectedValue); 
     }    
}
```

But as Response is final class not able to mock. Any way i can instantiate powermock Response  class?

I just need to power mock Response class of type Feign client . I have to test the catch block for better code coverage. But not able to instantiate/mock Response object. please help me on this